# Do I need to keep a copy of js library in lib or vendor folder though already installed using npm?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, single-page-application

**Question 1 :**
I am installing my project dependency libraries using npm and it gets stored in the `npm_modules` folder. Is it necessary to keep the copy of library like `angular.js`,`angular-route.js` in **lib** folder or **vendor** folder? I could see few people are using **lib** folder or **vendor** folders to store the library in the permanent manner. I am confused by seeing this.

**Question 2:** 
Do I need to copy/paste the **node_modules** folder to production or just run the `npm install` command on the project folder's command prompt to install all the dependencies in production. How does a dependency library get promoted to production?

Thank you kindly for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how you need to deploy your site to production, really. Ultimately, you will probably want to **bundle** all your JS files into one or a few files, which are minified and sent with gzip compression.

How you bundle them is up to you. There are quite a few options:

- Browserify
- Webpack
- Grunt / gulp build process
- And many more besides

As to whether you need to keep a copy of these bundled javascript files under version control, well I think that boils down to 1 key question: can you run a build process (such as one of the tools using NodeJS) on the production server, or on a build server that creates a zip file or installer? If so, then you don't need to include them, just get the build server or production server to check out the latest copy from version control, `npm install` and then run the build process.

But if the best you could do is have the production server check files out from source control, then you would want to include the final versions of the files to use in the repository.

Keeping *generated files*, such as your bundled javascript files, in your source control repo should be avoided where possible. Because otherwise, every commit has to contain the changes to the source files, and the corresponding change to the generated files as well. And the latter is just noise, and has to be ignored by every developer looking at a diff/patch for a commit.